# Match part of a String with a part of another String

Tags: javascript, regex

so this is my problem:
i have 2 Strings "myTestTomorrow" and "ThisIsmyTesttoday". I need to get the part which both strings contain, in this case "myTest". How can i do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp This is a question for Google, not for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why on earth has this received 2 upvotes? This is an awful question. OP: include what you've already attempted.

Comment: Do you know the string you are trying to find or are you trying to find the part of both strings that is the same? If you already know the string writing a RegEx for it is trivial, if not you probably can't accomplish it with a RegEx.

Comment: No i dont know which part i'm trying to find. I need to find out what part of both strings is the same. "myTest" is the string i'm trying to get out of those 2 Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two for loops and `indexOf`, like this

```
var text1 = "myTestTomorrow", text2 = "ThisIsmyTesttoday";
outer: for (var i = text1.length; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j + i < text1.length; j += 1) {
        if (text2.indexOf(text1.substr(j, i)) !== -1) {
            console.log("Result is '" + text1.substr(j, i) + "'");
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Result is 'myTest'
```

Comment: @user3197979 You are welcome :) Remember, there could be efficient implementations for the same algorithm.